# Safari can't find global const variable used in function (Can't find variable error)

Tags: javascript, macos, safari

JavaScript in Safari fails and execution is stopped if `const` is used within `function`. All other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, ...) work correctly, even on macOS.

My code (simplified):

```js
const a = 1;

function f() {
  console.log(a);
}
f();
```

In JavaScript console I can see:
`[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: a`

I resolved it by changing `const` to `var` and it started to work immediately. (I didn't try `let`).

```js
    var a = 1;
    function f() {
      console.log(a);
    }
    f();
```

I tried to investigate and understand why this is a problem. However, none of the resources gave me an answer why `const` should not work within `function`:

- [JavaScript Const](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_const.asp)
- [JavaScript Scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Is it something to do with Safari (security?) settings?

Unfortunately, I can't troubleshoot this further as I'm working on Windows and don't have macOS available all the time.

Comment: I tested this in Safari Version 15.1 and it works as expected with `const`. Are you using on old Windows version of Safari?

Comment: No, this was based on reports of our macOS users (latest Safari). Afaik, Safari on Windows was discontinued several years ago.

Comment: I can't reproduce it with the code you posted. But if I put that code inside an `if` block, the error occurs. It seems that you simplified it too much.

Comment: Indeed sounds very much like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57243751 (always "use strict").

Comment: @Barmar, yes, possibly, I might have simplified it too much. I'll try to to reproduce it again with `if` instead of `function`.